# Как адаптивно верстать ios приложение в storyboard?

Tags: swift, адаптивная-верстка, storyboard

Посмотрел несколько уроков по адаптации(Auto layout, Constraints), но не понял, как уменьшать шрифт, кнопки и тд. в зависимости от размера экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если на 11 Айфоне все хорошо влезает, то начиная уже с SE 2-поколения элементы налезают на друг друга.

**Что нужно сделать, чтобы регулировать размеры элементов в зависимости от размера дисплея?**

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет вот этот тьюториал:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started

Чтобы верстка выглядела одинаково на всех устройствах, нужно использовать size classes, почитать про них можно вот здесь, например:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started